# SQL How to get all dates within order range for all orders

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by

Using SQL Server
I need to get an array of all dates within an order range from order start, but excluding the order end date.

[image]

Comment: try `UNION` maybe?

Comment: Why `20190615` twice and `20190617` returned once? There is something wrong there.

Comment: Each order has a start and end date.  I require all dates from within the order period except the last date.  Output is order ids and date.